# Why does physics interpolation give me periodic jumps/flickers?

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, interpolation, fixed-timestep

I have seen [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18724/66142) but it didn't solve the problem.

I have followed the same steps as in [this article](http://www.unagames.com/blog/daniele/2010/06/fixed-time-step-implementation-box2d).

What I notice in my Android game is that my interpolation alpha (or fraction or accumulatorRatio) varies with this pattern as frames progress:

```
0.13
0.22
0.31
0.45
0.49
0.62
0.81
0.94
0.03
0.1
```

The above is an illustration but the point is that it goes from 0 to 1 and **cycles** back to 0 periodically. I believe this is due to the game frame rate being slight faster than the physics update interval.

Every time the interpolation alpha **cycles** around, it gives me a jitter (or jump).

Here is a log file: http://pastebin.com/3Yb7nVxX

The two columns are (i) interpolation alpha (ii) physics step count

The "jumps" happen roughly in lines 262 to 266 in the log.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/vWC7yNGM

What is causing these periodic "jumps"?

**EDIT:** Here is more detailed code: http://pastebin.com/PSZrntZP

Comment: I think this alpha is supposed to cycle around, and when it does it means the simulation executed one more loop.... maybe this is why one need to implement also the value interpolation. you know that technique that uses this alpha to interpolate all values between frame n-1 and n ?

Comment: @v.oddou by value interpolation, you mean position interpolation? I'm already doing linear position interpolation between frame n-1 and n. Is that what you meant?

Comment: It looks like you might have the order of terms in your interpolation function backwards. I'm used to seeing the order (oldValue, newValue, interpolationFactor), but if I'm reading correctly it looks like you have (newValue, oldValue, interpolationFactor). That would cause the rendered objects to move slightly slower than physics, until the cycle point where the rendered objects would jump forward in time about 1 physics step - does that sound like your symptom?

Comment: @DMGregory um, are you saying I'm using the wrong interpolation formula? regardless of the order of the parameters, I'm sure the body of the function is right and I'm passing the right new and old values. I even changed it like you said and it's worse. It's jittery all the time :)

Comment: Well, there goes one hypothesis. Can you post a video or gif of what you're seeing? There's multiple ways for interpolation to jump or jitter, and the particular appearance might help us diagnose what's going wrong.